# Where can requests for Glass Development Kit be submitted?

Tags: google-glass

The presentation today indicated that there was support on Stackoverflow but I was wondering if there's a central location where all requests are being tracked for us to follow and vote on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a very specific request for the Glass Development Kit, the best place to file it is in the [Glass API issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list). There's a Component-GDK tag being used for these requests.

In general, though, not much has been said about the GDK yet, so it may be a bit early to make specific issue requests until more context is available.

For now, if you're a member of the Explorer Program, the Glass Pioneers section of the [Glass Community](http://www.glass-community.com/) is a great place to discuss your thoughts on the GDK.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "request new API Features" link on the [Glass API issue tracker page](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/), but it's not clear if that is the best place for GDK feature requests since a lot of the branding on the page lists it as the Google Mirror API issue tracker. There seem to be a few GDK-ish feature requests in that issue tracker though, so in the absence of any official information I'd probably submit them there.