# Will GDK (Glass NDK?) Support OpenGL ES?

Tags: google-glass

Does anyone know, will Google Glass support OpenGL ES? If so will it be 1.1? 2? WebGL?

I am sure this will probably have to be done using the GDK (GNDK?) when it is released but are there plans to make it possible?

Comment: Any particular reason people are downvoting this? I would be more than happy to delete it but I don't understand why it is an invalid question? Is it due to being an invalid tag? Since this isn't technically the Mirror API?

Comment: SO is a herd of sheep sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it supports OpenGLES (same as of Android 4.0.4 release) - I've side loaded and tested a OpenGLES open source game Seven Wonders with minor modifications (removed ads) and it performs well.

Comment: Is this game written in Java or does it use the NDK (if existing on Glass)?

Comment: in pure Java, works with Glass, Wear, Cardboard VR, yes blogpost still forthcoming

Answer (score 4):

In the [Developing For Glass](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332490621) session at Google I/O (the video seems to be down right now for me), I remember Timothy Jordan saying that the Glass team isn't commenting on what will be in the GDK right now, but that they would by all means like to hear feedback on what people would like to see in the GDK and the reasons why.

I'm not absolutely sure where to submit those requests at this point, but you can check this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596403/where-can-requests-for-glass-development-kit-be-submitted) regarding that subject and hopefully the Glass team will give an official answer in the near future.

Comment: I got that I didn't know if there were any community comments, since people should know (since they show you how to root). I am not lucky enough to have a device so I figured I would ask here. I don't get where all the hate comes from in terms of the down votes. Seems like a valid question even if the answer is, as you say, nothing official for a while.