# Google Glass documentation

Tags: opengl-es, google-glass, inertial-navigation

As I cannot find anything in the docs and support is no help, is there anyone that knows about:

1) OpenGL ES support

2) IMUs access API

3) camera specs (focal length, sensor size etc.)

I want to work on something more advanced than another instagram app, that is computer vision, but... is it possible?

**Update:**

1) OpenGL ES 2.0 support: [Will GDK (Glass NDK?) Support OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627137/will-gdk-glass-ndk-support-opengl-es)

2) IMUs are accessible through `GDK`: http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/68954384185/google-glass-development-kit-gdk-sample-code-motion

Comment: As of now, camera returns focusMode "infinity".

Answer (score 0):

According to the articles reference below the camera has the following specs:

- 3mm focal length
- F/2.5 min.
- ISO 60-960
- 720 p video
- 5 megapixel photos at 2560 x 1888

http://www.itproportal.com/2013/05/16/google-glass-hands-on-preview/

http://phandroid.com/2013/05/09/google-glass-camera-review/

Comment: Focal length is cited as `2.8mm` in one of the articles and `3mm` in the other article. The sensor size would also be important (updated my question).